# Save as Values Only from Formulas, Recognizing Columns with Formulas

Tags: vba, excel

Using an Excel 2013 workbook, I have changed my Col F and Col AD from formulas to values only in the MFG Hourly Employees worksheet. Is there a way to tweak my code to recognize the first column that has formulas and save as values only, and then the second column the same (currently F4 and AD 4). My code so far is:

```
  Sub SaveAsValuesOnly()
    Sheets("MFG Hourly Employees").Select
    Range("F4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("AD4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("F4").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: [range.hasformula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837123.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim rngCell As Range 

For Each rngCell In Selection  
    If rngCell.HasFormula Then  
        rngCell.Value = rngCell.Value  
    End If   
Next
```

The

```
rng.Value = rng.Value
```

Removes formulas and keeps values. It looks like you recorded the Makro so i will point it out.
Edit: longer moreexplicit Code with explanation.

```
Sub removeFormulas()
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim searchRange As Range    
searchRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10") 

For each rngCell In searchRange
      If rngCell.HasFormula Then
          rngCell.Value = rngCell.Value
      End If
Next
End Sub
```

Explanation:
First we start a sub which is a subprogramm, which will do the trick for your problem.  The Sub is started by   `Sub removeFormulas()` and ended with `End Sub`.  Now we set our Variables with `Dim X As Y`where `X` is the Name and `Y` the Datatype, here it is the `Range` Object.
Now we set our `searchRange`, in which we want to look for formulas, you can set this to fit your needs.  In the `For` Loop we can Loop through every `rngCell` in our `searchRange` When we hit `Next` We return to `For`, till we looped through all cells in `searchRange`.  The If statement obviosly chekcsif the Cell contains any Formula with the `.HasFormula` attribute and when it has a formula we just write the visible `.Value` in the cell and overwrite the formula.

Comment: Thanks so much Johannes. Yes I did record the macro. What shows up in the recording is exactly when needs to happen every run (every 2 weeks) but exactly one column over for both of the columns noted. Sorry, but I have a long way to go with all this. Thanks for your patience. BTW, I got a compile error with the above code.

Comment: Yes it is no complete Code you have to write it into a Sub, do you have a working solution by now ? For getting started with VBA i would recommend trying some Tutorial, if you want i can give you some advice too

Comment: Sure. Would appreciate it.

Comment: I need to figure out how to make this work, but I'm really not figuring it out. So thanks.

Comment: Can it wait till tomorrow?

Comment: @KimG there you go

Comment: Thanks! And great explanation.

Comment: If it works i would be happy if you would accept the answer